# Sci-Kit Learn Classifier Loading issue : Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty! when using transform

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I am working through the Sci-Kit learn tutorial at https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial.

I deviated slightly from the tutorial by making the tutorial into 2 files, one where the classifier is trained, and saves the classifier to a file. Another file to load the classifier and predict sentiment on a `testFile`. The original program calls for performing transform on a vectorizer, however I get the error:

```
Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty! at the line :
test_data_features = vectorizer.transform(clean_test_reviews)
```

I also need to initialize a vectorizer object in this file, as the vectorizer was in the last file. If I change the line to `fit_transform`, the program runs and does print out a file with label as expected. I do worry that I may have made a logic error though by learning the vocab on the test set, then fitting the array. Here is the code to load the classifier, prepare the test array, predict and write results to file. Other answers I have seen say just load the pickle file and try to predict, but I am not sure how to get the `clean_test_reviews` into the right data structure to then pass to predict. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
##load the classifier

forest = joblib.load(classifier)### put in the name of the classifer, 'filename.pkl'


# Read the test data
test = pd.read_csv(infile, header=0, delimiter="\t", \
quoting=3 ) #infile is testData.tsv

# Verify that there are 25,000 rows and 2 columns
print "Test shape(Rows, Columns of Data):", test.shape

# Create an empty list and append the clean reviews one by one
num_reviews = len(test["review"])    
clean_test_reviews = []

print "Cleaning and parsing the test set...\n"
for i in xrange(0,num_reviews):
    if( (i+1) % 1000 == 0 ):
        print "Review %d of %d\n" % (i+1, num_reviews)
    clean_review = review_to_words( test["review"][i] )
    clean_test_reviews.append( clean_review )

# Initialize the "CountVectorizer" object, which is scikit-learn's
# bag of words tool.  


vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word", \ tokenizer = None, \ preprocessor = None, \ stop_words = None, \ max_features = 5000) 
# Get a bag of words for the test set, and convert to a numpy array
test_data_features = vectorizer.transform(clean_test_reviews)
test_data_features = test_data_features.toarray()
print "Test data feature shape:", test_data_features.shape

# Take a look at the words in the vocabulary
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print vocab

# Use the random forest to make sentiment label predictions
result = forest.predict(test_data_features)

# Copy the results to a pandas dataframe with an "id" column and
# a "sentiment" column
output = pd.DataFrame( data={"id":test["id"], "sentiment":result} )

# Use pandas to write the comma-separated output file
output.to_csv( outfile, index=False, quoting=3 ) # "Bag_of_Words_model.csv",
```

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/alvations/bayesmax/blob/master/experiments.py#L109

Comment: I edited this after fixing.. removing fit_transform as I do not want someone to copy and create a logic error for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to worry about fitting your `CountVectorizer` on the test set. When using the `CountVectorizer`, if you call `fit()` on two different datasets, you will get two incompatible vectorizers with different vocabulary dicts. Instead you should use `pickle` or `joblib` to save the vectorizer to a file as well as the classifier. you are currently saving.

Comment: David: thank so much for the answer. I suspected that i was doing something wrong. Can you tell me how to fix the code above? I did use jobliib.dump which dumps the classifier and bunch of other files (i assume that is the vectors). In this file, i use joblib.load on the .pkl file, which i assumed was pulling in the vectors in addition to the classifier. Do i need to call something else to read in the vectors ? Thanks!

Comment: Here's what the documentation says : 
>>> from sklearn.externals import joblib
>>> joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl') 

Later you can load back the pickled model (possibly in another Python process) with:
>>>>>> clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl') 
Note:
 joblib.dump returns a list of filenames. Each individual numpy array contained in the clf object is serialized as a separate file on the filesystem. All files are required in the same folder when reloading the model with joblib.load. There is a large amount of numpy arrays in the folder I dumped the classifier to.

Comment: Yes. It should be able to save and load it exactly the same as you are now doing with your classifier`forest`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on David Maust's answer above, I was able to fix it.... in the first file dump the vectorizer like this:

```
joblib.dump(vectorizer.vocabulary_, dictionary_file_path) #dictionary_file_path is something like "./Vectorizer/vectorizer.pkl"
```

Note the underscore on the vectorizer.vocabulary_ attribute. In the loading file, load the vectorizer like this :

```
vocabulary_to_load =joblib.load(dictionary_file_path)

loaded_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary_to_load)
```

... now use the vectorizer for transform

Comment: do you have any clue why vocabulary loading takes 14 sec. is there a way to make it faster??